# OpenWrt/LEDE:Mosquitto unable to create websockets listener on any port when enable SSL

Tags: ssl, mosquitto, openwrt

When the mosquitto config:

```
port 1883
listener 443
protocol websockets
```

It works well.
And I want to enable SSL/TLS support:

```
port 1883
listener 443
protocol websockets
cafile   /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile  /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
```

I get an error:

> Error: Unable to create websockets listener on port 443

The menuconfig:

```
->Network->mosquitto-ssl =y
->Libraries->SSL->libopenssl->Enable support for TLS 1.3 =y
```

Any ideas of how can I enable SSL/TLS support for mosquitto on my device?

Comment: Have you tried ports other than 443? I'm going to guess that 443 is already in use by something e.g. the admin web interface.

Comment: Yes I have.And other is same.But if I disable SSL/TLS support, the port can be open, and the mosquitto work well.

Comment: OK, and you sure all the cert/key files are properly formatted and have the right permissions for the user running mosquitto (which will have to be root to use port 443)?

Comment: I have the right permissions on my Openwrt device. But I can't sure the cert/key files are right.The cert/key files is generated by myself.I use same way to generated other cert/key files, and I used them in another device which system is Ubuntu,in that device the mosquitto with WSS is right.